# How can I add a video camera shortcut to the home screen?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, video-recording, android-11

My Pixel 3 (standard size--why no tag?) had both camera and video shortcuts on the home screen. I must've pocked-edited it, because the video camera one is gone. I can't figure out how to add it back. There's no dedicated video camera app.

Thanks much.

Comment: You may be able to recreate the shortcut using this app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut&hl=en_IN&gl=US

Answer (score 0):

Long press on the default camera icon from the home screen and there should be popup menu with "Take a video"

[image: Screenshot of Pixel 2 default Camera app long press icon menu]

Press and hold on "Take a video" from the popup menu to create a "Take a Video" shortcut which you can drag and place on your home screen.

Comment: Thanks, but that's one of the first things I tried. It's not like that anymore. I get 'Pause app' and 'App info' in Android 11.

Comment: Strange. I'm running a Pixel 2, Android 10 OS, Pixel Launcher version 10, Camera version 7.4.201.322479879. I don't see any options in Pixel Launcher settings that would block the behavior. A suggestion would be to try Nova Launcher but as I'm reading through the Google Play feedback, I see some similar reports and noticed: https://9to5google.com/2020/01/01/pixel-launcher-icons-disappear/.